# What is the distance between the 3' 18s rRNA (the Kozak consensus sequence) and the A-site of eukaryotic ribosomes during protein translation?

Tags: structural-biology, ribosome

Reposted from [Quora](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-distance-between-the-3-18s-rRNA-the-Kozak-consensus-sequence-and-the-A-site-of-eukaryotic-ribosomes-during-protein-translation)

The Kozak sequence is shown to be important in translation initiation, and the A-site is the anti-codon recognition site. If the distance is not known, how could I find out what it is? Is the crystal structure of the whole mRNA-rRNA-tRNA complex determined? If so, what modeling program would be best for establishing intermolecular distances?

Answer (score 1):

Kozak consensus sequence (KCS) is present near or overlapping with the start codon. I am not sure what you mean by distance between that and A-site. Start codon is localaized at P-site at the time of translation initiation. Distance between start codon/KCS and A-site at initiation is same as distance between P- and A- sites (I guess ~20Å). A-site keeps moving during translation and hence the distance keeps increasing. Crystal study is available; See [here](http://www.cell.com/cell/fulltext/S0092-8674%2814%2901281-1).

See this figure from the abovementioned study for the relative positions of start-codon, P-site (exit) and A-site (entry).

[image]